# Macro loop through and update some cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet (Master) which should be updated periodically based on information in another sheet (NewData). In column A there is an unique id in both sheets. In the NewData sheet there might be some new id's which should be transferred to the Master sheet, and if the NewData sheet failes to have an id which is registered in the Master sheet, this id (entire row) should be removed from Master sheet. In other words: The NewData sheet gives the blueprint of which id's to be in the Master sheet.

The NewData sheet contains updated data to some of the columns in the Master sheet. I can't blindly copy the information between the two sheets because the user might have put a hyperlink in the cell - and that hyperlink should not be deleted.

Example:

[The Master sheet looks like this before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ezny.jpg)

[The NewData sheet looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSVmk.jpg)

I am not allowed to post more than two links, so I have to verbally describe how the updated Master sheet shoukd look like after running the macro:

- Rowid 2001 (Kjell) should be unchanged
- Rowid 2345 (Vegard) should be removed (as it is not in the NewData
  sheet)
- Rowid 1002 (Fenja) should be almost as in original Master, but
  with a new description and a new date, and now a date without the
  hyperlink.
- Rowid 1234 () should be as a new row (without data in Name cell)

I guess this can be solved by rather simple vba-programming, but I don't even have basic knowledge, and after trying a lot of copy/paste, trying vlookup and index-match and... I took the step to bother this community... Very glad if any could help me!

Comment: The examples show only 3 records. I presume this is an excerpt of a much larger dataset. I don't think the code will be 'rather simple'. I recommend you migrate this to a RDBMS such as Access. Then build UPDATE and INSERT queries to accomplish these edits. Otherwise, attempt to develop code - try using the macro editor to help. When you have code with specific issue, post it for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I assume each of the row ids are unique in both worksheets.  If so you can use a dictionary object and populate it with all the values in the Master worksheet.  Once that's done you can iterate through the NewData worksheet and if an encountered id exists in the dictionary, then update the Master record (ie that record is in both Master and NewData);  note, that you delete the dictionary key/value pair once that's done.   If it doesn't exist then you append it to the end of the Master worksheet (ie that record is in NewData but not in Master).

After that loop completes the only entries in the dictionary are keys that exist in Master but not in NewData and can be deleted - which is what's done in the last loop:

```
Option Explicit


Sub updateMaster()
  Dim dict As Object
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Dim wrkM As Worksheet: Set wrkM = Worksheets("Master")
  Dim wrkD As Worksheet: Set wrkD = Worksheets("NewData")

  Dim r As Integer, r1 As Integer, lr As Integer
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim val As String
  With wrkM:
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For r = 2 To lr:
      Set rng = .Range("A" & r).EntireRow
      val = Trim(.Cells(r, "A").Value)
      Set dict(val) = rng
    Next
  End With
  lr = lr + 1

  Dim str As Variant
  With wrkD:
    For r = 2 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row:
      str = Trim(.Cells(r, "A").Value)
      If dict.Exists(str) Then
        Set rng = dict(str)
        r1 = rng.row
        wrkM.Cells(r1, "B").Value = .Cells(r, "B").Value
        wrkM.Cells(r1, "E").Value = .Cells(r, "C").Value
        wrkM.Cells(r1, "D").Value = .Cells(r, "D").Value
        dict.Remove str
      Else
        wrkM.Cells(lr, "A").Value = .Cells(r, "A").Value
        wrkM.Cells(lr, "B").Value = .Cells(r, "B").Value
        wrkM.Cells(lr, "D").Value = .Cells(r, "D").Value
        wrkM.Cells(lr, "E").Value = .Cells(r, "C").Value
        lr = lr + 1
      End If
    Next
  End With

  For Each str In dict.keys():
     Set rng = dict(str)
     rng.Delete
  Next

End Sub
```

If you have a contiguous range you can replace the 1st 2 rows in the else condition with the following:

```
.Range("A" & r, "B" & r).Copy Destination:=wrkM.Range("A" & lr, "B" & lr)
```

but for just 2 rows it isn't as efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It seems to work the way I wanted it to, but I still have some trouble after trying to transfer the code into my real workbook. One trouble I have is the fact that I have two sheets that shall be updated from the NewData-file. I tried to copy the whole code and change in the copy from wrkM to wrkM2, I will try a bit more, and may be come back to you. One question though: is it necessary to sort any of the sheets before running the macro, or as part of the macro?

Comment: You want to run the subroutine twice once each time for a different master sheet but with the same NewData sheet?  If so you can pass in the Master sheet as a parameter to the subroutine.  If that's the case I can modify the code to do that.   As for sorting, you don't have to if you don't want to.

Comment: I will try to explain better. The users of this workbook will from time to time paste new data into the NewData sheet. In the NewData sheet I have made a button they shall click to activate the macro. The macro should then transfer data to Master sheet AND the other sheet (Master2). In the Master sheet the user can follow his/her project with some key dates. In the Master2 sheet the user can do the same, but in this sheet there are far more columns than in Master sheet. The extra columns in Master2 sheet will be updated manually directly in the sheet by the user.

Comment: If I'm following you correctly - the same entries exist in both Master and Master2 and you want to update both sheets using the above macro.   If that's the case they you would have to run the macro twice, once for each sheet since the records could be in different rows on each sheet.

Comment: It's not a big deal for me to change it to get that sort of functionality.  All what's need is a new macro that calls the macro above but with a different master each time.  The only change to the above macro is to add a subroutine parameter for the master worksheet.

Comment: Yes, making two macros and let one of them call the other should be smart, I guess. At the moment I'm struggeling a bit to transfer your code into my real workbook.  The reason is I do not understand what your code is doing... Why "wrkM.Cells(r1, "E").Value = .Cells(r, "C").Value" and "wrkM.Cells(r1, "D").Value = .Cells(r, "D").Values" and not "wrkM.Cells(r1, "B").Value = .Cells(r, "B").Value"? The B column should in principle like the E/C-columns and the D-columns?
        wrkM.Cells(r1, "D").Value = .Cells(r, "D").Value

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to add the "B" column as well - just changed the code to show that.